# Coffeescript extern property store for child class

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I write program in nodejs (latest ver.) with **hot class reloading**.

It means i create some objects, use them in the program and change their properties and variables. Then i change some classes source code, requiring their files again and recreate every object.

After linking new objects to previous states all previous properies and variables should be available as before.

And every access operation to them should transfer to store **implicitly**. 
(store = this) but parent class methods should be available too.

I guess redeclaring all unpure functions (store dependable) after connectining to the storage is necessary operation.

How can i change parent class to get this behavior ?

**Example**

**Discription:**

`Class B` extends `class A` that have properties and methods.

I also have object `store` object b of Class B get in constructor.

All methods and properties i declare in child should be contained **only** in `store`.

Can i get such execution as below and how?

**Code:**

```
store = {}
class A
    constructor: (store)->
        @val = 10
        # some actions with 'store' there or anywhere
        # but child class

class B extends A
    constructor: ->
        super
        @val2 = 20

b = new B(store)
console.log b.val           
console.log b.val2          
console.log store.val2

# I GET -> I WANT TO GET
# 10 -> 10
# 20 -> undefined
# undefined -> 20
```

[jsfiddle working example](https://jsfiddle.net/531hrnjj/1/)

*working* means no syntax errors

**edited (26.02.16):**

Sorry for bad in example

**edited (26.02.16):**

Extended the discription.

Comment: Your indentation looks messed up, I'm getting a syntax error. What are you really doing?

Comment: Where does any of your class constructors take an object such as `store` as a parameter?

Comment: I don't get what you want to use this `store` for. Are logs depicting the expected or the non-expected behaviour?

Comment: Fixed code example, discription, added url to jsfiddle with wroking example

Comment: I see. But I still don't really get *why* you want this? And which access operations exactly should silently be transferred?

Comment: I extended the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the *particular* problem can be solved very simple way if the time of class change is known.

How **hot class reloading** can be done (algorithm):

1. (moment of class change `A1` to `A2`)
2. save own properties of object `a` to external object `store`
3. recreate object `a` with class `A2`
4. load properties from the object `store`

**Code:**

```
store = {}
class A
  constructor: -> @val = 10

  saveTo: (store)->
    for own name, val of @
      store[name] = val

  loadFrom: (store)->
    for own name, val of store
      @[name] = val

class B1 extends A
  dataChange: -> @val2 = 20
class B2 extends A

b = new B1 ; b.dataChange()
console.log b # GOT : B1 {val: 10, val2: 20}
# RELOADED class
store = {}
b.saveTo(store)
# RECREATION of new object
b = new B2
b.loadFrom(store)
console.log b # GOT : B2 {val: 10, val2: 20}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/531hrnjj/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write your subclass constructor so that it explicitly puts the properties on that store, not on the instance:

```
store = {}
class A
    constructor: ->
        @val = 10

class B extends A
    constructor: (s) ->
        super
        s.val2 = 20

b = new B(store)
console.log b.val # 10           
console.log b.val2 # undefined      
console.log store.val2 # 20
```

There's not really a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). Create it in B constructor and return it from B constructor. Proxy would be set up in such way that it would forward all property writes and reads to `store` except those that are present in B prototype (those inherited from A), those should be forwarded to real instance of B or directly to prototype of B.

Not sure if you can get it running on nodejs because Proxy is ES6 feature, not supported natively yet on node. Babel also doesn't support it. It's available in Firefox, MS Edge and upcoming versions of Chrome.

https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Proxy

There is a version of nodejs that uses MS javascript engine instead of Chrome's V8 but I haven't used it and I don't know if it has Proxy objects: https://github.com/nodejs/node-chakracore

Comment: Nodejs 5.7 still doesnt support proxy